# Run onEdit script in one sheet only

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have this Script so far,

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 2 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/DD/yy, hh:mm:ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
 };
```

but what I am trying to get this to only run on one of my Google Sheet tabs. Tried adding

```
var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(sheet.getName()=='Inventory'){
```

But I couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 2):

Checking the name of the sheet would be like this:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() == 'Inventory') {
    // the rest of the script
  }
}
```

The line you were trying, with `event.source.getActiveSheet()` would work if you actually took the event object as a parameter: `onEdit(event)`.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet(); 
  //  etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding additional cell (which can be hidden after)
to copy changing cell's data (... .setValue(time))
and manipulate the data in other sheets 
can be a quick solution in some variants.