# Automatically sort 1 sheet on edit

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, sorting

I have a google spreadsheet with multiple sheets.

On one of the sheets, we use Zapier to populate new rows of data when a meeting is scheduled with our team.  I'd like the sheet "Meetings" **to automatically sort by date,** descending in column P (16).  The sheet is A:AW.

When a new line is added by Zapier it is not in order by date.

I would like 1 sheet, "Meetings", to be auto-sorted whenever a new row is added.

I'm looking for a script and how to add it to the worksheet that will help auto-sort the sheet by date.

Every time I open the sheet I'd like it to be sorted by column P in descending order.

Comment: I've found other threads but they don't seem to help with only updating 1 sheet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does that help.  I just need a script to help me automatically sort a sheet by date instead of me having to do that every time I open the sheet.

Comment: You might use a Google Apps Script change installable trigger to automatically run a Google Apps Script function sort the data. Please show what you already know about using Google Apps Script. If you don't know nothing, please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make some data on a Google Sheets auto-sorting?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7211/how-can-i-make-some-data-on-a-google-sheets-auto-sorting)

Comment: The script might work, but how do I only get it to work with the sheet "Meetings"
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 4;
  var tableRange = "B3:E9";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
  }
}

Comment: You need to adapt that script to your scenario. Have a look at [Run onEdit script in one sheet only](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/94532/196152) as a way to target a specific sheet. You might also use `getDataRange()`, rather than trying to define a specific range, it will be more efficient. So far as sorting when you open the spreadsheet, would you please explain why you want this? I'm not familiar with Zapier, but if users are editing "Meetings" then you should probably consider an `onChange` installable trigger (with a "Change Type" of `INSERT_ROW`) instead of an onEdit trigger.